# Поисковые подсказки по своим данным яндекс карты api

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

В данном [примере](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search) показано как сделать поиск по своим объектам на самой яндекс карте. Проблема в том, что при вводе текста не отображается выпадающая панель с найденными объектами.

Вопрос: Как добавить возможность отображения выпадающей панели через поиск по своим объектам именно на яндекс карте?

Answer (score 0):

Выпадающая панель не отображается, потому что в примере у всех объектов уникальные названия — если вписать всё слово целиком, то будет сразу найден единственный релевантный вариант. А если напишите в поиске, например, одну только букву "Б" — получите выпадающую панель ;-)

Помимо панели с результатами поиска (которая появляется после нажатия Enter), существует панель поисковых подсказок, для которой также можно назначить кастомный провайдер. Пример [тут](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest).